# Jenkins build for Xamarin.Android project with Signing and Alignment

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build Xamarin.Android app using Jenkins using [this guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/).
Everything works fine expect except signature and alignment of the APK.

```
KEYSTORE_FILE = $WORKSPACE/Solutions Items/helloworld.keystore
KEYSTORE_ALIAS = helloworld 
INPUT_APK = $WORKSPACE/helloworld.Android/bin/Release/helloworld.android.apk
SIGNED_APK = $WORKSPACE/helloworld.Android/bin/Release/helloworld.android-Signed.apk
FINAL_APK = $WORKSPACE/helloworld.android-Aligned.apk
STORE_PASS = mystrong_pass
```

I can put STORE_PASS as a password using "Inject passwords to the build as environment variables" but but this topic about another thing. After env injection I add jarsigner:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass $STORE_PASS -signedjar $SIGNED_APK $INPUT_APK $KEYSTORE_ALIAS 
zipalign -f -v 4 $SIGNED_APK $FINAL_APK
```

After that I'm starting the build and at the end getting the following error:
    **Enter Passphrase for keystore: jarsigner: you must enter key password**

but password is provided as you can see above

```
Build succeeded.
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
KEYSTORE_FILE=$WORKSPACE/Solutions Items/helloworld.keystore
KEYSTORE_ALIAS=helloworld
INPUT_APK=$WORKSPACE/helloworld.Android/bin/Release/helloworld.android.apk
SIGNED_APK=$WORKSPACE/helloworld.Android/bin/Release/helloworld.android-Signed.apk
FINAL_APK=$WORKSPACE/helloworld.android-Aligned.apk
STORE_PASS=mystrong_pass

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[Xamarin Test Build] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/vy/ty4s4j.......ygm0000gy/T/hudson18473.......171797.sh
+ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /Users/user/.jenkins/workspace/Xamarin Test Build/Solutions Items/helloworld.keystore -storepass mystrong_pass -signedjar /Users/a.strakh/.jenkins/workspace/Xamarin Test Build/helloworld.Android/bin/Release/helloworld.android-Signed.apk /Users/a.strakh/.jenkins/workspace/Xamarin Test Build/helloworld.Android/bin/Release/helloworld.android.apk helloworld
Enter Passphrase for keystore: jarsigner: you must enter key password
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Skipped archiving because build is not successful
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Does your store password have special characters in it? You would need to escape those. Instead of

```
-storepass $STORE_PASS
```

try

```
-storepass "${STORE_PASS}"
```

If that doesn't help change your store password to something using only alphanumerics (no special chars). Alphanumerics do not need to be escaped on the command line.